# How to batch organize files?

Tags: 12.04, bash, sed, awk, scripts

I have a directory with gigabytes (about 8gb) of small individual files. I want to organize them into directories by date. The date it was created is part of the filename.

Here is an example of a filename:

```
4RCPBlockCoverLtrednalaserfalse07-10-2012-11-50-14-656.doc.gz
```

I want the docs directory setup like this:

```
docs_by_date
    2013
        01
        02
        03
        04
```

If the destination directory does not exist it should be created. After verification of a successful copy the source file should be removed.

I'm no super guru with bash, a lot of the symbols I still don't know what they mean, so an explanation would be great of what the script is doing.

Comment: Is that a consistent representation of the filename? i.e. will they always end in `07-10-2012-11-50-14-656.doc.gz` (with different digits)?

Comment: Those are the dates that change.  07-10-2012 (the rest is item numbers and seconds, etc) which I don't care about.  It's the 07-10-2012 which needs to be organized by.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the FORMAT will stay the same, though the numbers will change.  You are correct sir.

Comment: So I'm assuming that in this example, "10" is the month? Also, it seems that you don't want to organise by day, just year then month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made the assumption that for the file `07-10-2012-11-50-14-656.doc.gz`, you want it sorted by year (i.e. `2012`) and month (i.e. `10`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This is the preferred way of invoking a bash script, and is better than #!/bin/bash for reasons of portability.
# To use the script, make it executable with `chmod u+x /path/to/script`
# Then run this script with `/path/to/script /path/to/original/files /path/to/docs_by_date`

# Let's set up some path variables. This script will transfer files from the directory specified by the first argument to the directory specified by the second.
pathtooriginalfiles=$1
pathtotarget=$2

# Lets iterate over the files in the original directory, by listing all non-invisible files with $(ls ${pathtooriginalfiles}), and repeating the block with $i changing each time.
for i in $(ls "${pathtooriginalfiles}"); do
  # Find the matching parts of the filename that specify the date by echoing then piping the variable to sed. The regex part looks for "everything at the beginning" ^.*, followed by two iterations of digits [0-9]{2}, followed by four iterations of digits, etc. before ending with .doc.gz. It then replaces this entire string with what matches between () using the \1 variable, i.e. the year or month.
  year=$(echo -n ${i}| sed -r 's/^.*[0-9]{2}-([0-9]{4})-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}\.doc\.gz$/\1/')
  month=$(echo -n ${i}| sed -r 's/^.*([0-9]{2})-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}\.doc\.gz$/\1/')

  # Create the directory if it doesn't exist already, then copy into it.
  mkdir -p "${pathtotarget}/${year}/${month}"
  cp "${pathtooriginalfiles}/${i}" "${pathtotarget}/${year}/${month}"
done
```

Also, I haven't coded exactly what you requested. You said that it should test to see if the files are there, then automatically delete them. Instead, this script just copies them and leaves the originals alone. I'd recommend that you "test" it yourself manually to make sure it does what you think it should, rather than relying on the script to do that itself. (Any bugs in the copying part would probably be replicated in the checking part.) If you really want the script to remove originals, then just change the `cp` part to `mv` instead. (I feel that mv is cleaner than copying and deleting anyway. One reason is that `cp` doesn't checksum, although you could use `rsync -a` instead.

Comment: I tried the script.  It worked, to a degree.  Instead of making folders for the year, it turns the whole filename into a folder and then copies it into it's own folder.

in a test environment, the folder that is created (mkdir -p)

Looks like this:

root@bigboy:/RAID5/RAID200/bicaword/docs_by_date/dates# ls | more
2224304CPNTexasCoverCPN_LASER_VICTORFALSE01-03-2012-19-38-52-863.doc.gz

The only 2 sections of the filename that matter for organizing, is the year and then month

Sorry took so long to reply! Been out

Comment: Oh!  It also looks like the Month variable is actually treating it as a daily variable  (unless there are 31 months in a year =P which is what is in the year folders, 31 other folders )

I just noted that it did create 2 folders.  A 2012 folder and a 2013 folder, which their subfolders are d/o/m rather than months. After that it created fldrs out of FNms

I'm still looking at your code trying to decipher it.  I think i'm getting it, though I dunno why all the brackets past the year and moth are there.  Are those needed, or can we just throw a "*" in to cover everything past the month and year?

Comment: So it looks like, the script works for the year part (Save for a mixup on my part.  I didn't realize that the last set of numbers right before doc.gz changes from 2 to 3 randomly.

But the months are what is being created as a full filename instead of 1-12

I've been playing with it like crazy.

This is definitely a simpler script than I had before!  I wish I knew SED better!

Comment: So I assume you know which part the regex is now. In this section, `[0-9]{2}` means a digit, twice; i.e. two digits. I put this messy part in (instead of a general `.*`) because I expected this part to be consistent in the filenames. Hence, the regex is essentially finding the part of the filename that is a month or year by counting back. i.e. find `.doc.gz` at the end, then before that, find `-##-##-##-###' (where # is a digit), and the four digits before this is the year. Preceded by the month. (cont'd)

Comment: I tried to make the script agnostic about what happens before this. If we went with your suggestion using `*` (actually, this is `.*` in regex), then it might get confused if there were digits and dashes in the first part. I figured it'd be better to trust the last part to be consistent.

Regarding the days/months problem, could it be that for `4RCPBlockCoverLtrednalaserfalse07-10-2012-11-50-14-656.doc.gz`, the month is actually 07, not 10?

Comment: Also, are you saying that there are sometimes 2, sometimes 3 digits just before the .doc.gz? That's easy to change. Also, I'm not sure if I understand if there's another problem. Are you saying that `4RCPBlockCoverLtrednalaserfalse07-10-2012-11-50-14-656.doc.gz` currently gets filed to `docs_by_date/2012/10/4RCPBlockCoverLtrednalaserfalse07-10-2012-11-50-14-656.doc.gz/4RCPBlockCoverLtrednalaserfalse07-10-2012-11-50-14-656.doc.gz`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the last 3 digits can be actually 2 digits.  The name of the file is turning into a directory name and then the file is filed under it, under the year and day of month.  Day-of-month is there instead of just month.

Yes, your script is making a lot more sense the more I look at it and play around with it.  Thank you for your help on this!!!

The only question now is the filename as a dir and the month being the sub dir (under year) instead of dom.

THANKS!

Comment: Also, found out that the {3} is given a range by putting in the comma {1,3}, so that sorted that out!

Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, that's right with the range. Good find. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like I figured it out, due to your help!

It was a simple error!  There are 7 fields, instead of 6!  If you look at the original filename:

4RCPBlockCoverLtrednalaserfalse **07**-10-**2012**-11-50-14-656.doc.gz

- the bold section is what we are going for.  Year (2012) and Month (7).  In the script it was treating 10 (inbetween the 07 and 2012) as the first field!  All I did was add the [0-9]{2} inbetween them and voila, it works!

This is the script you gave me and then you can see how I 'edited' it.

Thanks for your help sooooo much! Saved my day!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pathtooriginalfiles=$1
pathtotarget=$2

for i in $(ls "${pathtooriginalfiles}"); do

year=$(echo -n ${i}| sed -r 's/^.*[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-([0-9]{4})-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,3}\.doc\.gz$/\1/')
month=$(echo -n ${i}| sed -r 's/^.*([0-9]{2})-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,3}\.doc\.gz$/\1/')

echo $year $month
  mkdir -p "${pathtotarget}/${year}/${month}"
   ls -l $pathtotarget
  cp -auv "${pathtooriginalfiles}/${i}" "${pathtotarget}/${year}/${month}/"
done
```

the "," between the {1,3} was key for me personally.

and the "/" at the end of the cp string ${month}/" was key as well.

Comment: Glad you could work it out. I actually asked you a few times which field was the month, as I made the presumption that it was dd-mm-yyyy. (That's how we do it in Australia.) Anyway, I'm glad you worked it out in the end! (Although I'm still not sure why the filenames were becoming directory names. They certainly weren't in my testing.)

Comment: Yeah, kinda weird.  I have no idea either.

Sorry I missed your request on what day is month and year!  

There is one other thing I am running into on this script in my final tests.

It successfully creates the year and dir directory.

If I do

backup_script.sh /source /target  (And if Target already has the year/month tree) it restarts creating the year/month tree under the already existing tree.  

I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I can't see where it is.  mkdir -p should protect it from this.  But it seems to not be. =/  any idea?

Comment: Ok, looks like the cp command needed one last forward slash at the end ${month}/" instead of ${month}"